# How to remove deleted files inside Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-build, nvidia-docker

My docker image size is 17 GB. I ran the image and deleted a folder of 4GB inside docker container. After committing the container the new image created was also 17 GB . How is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

As you add another layer by committing this will result in an additional layer which deletes the files of of a previous layers. If you run an image all layers will be executed and interpreted.

[Docker: About images, containers, and storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)

`docker build --squash` can help you to reduce the image size as it **merges** all layers into one, but it is experimental.

Comment: You should read this answer as “a `docker commit`ted image will never be smaller than its predecessor”.

Comment: So technically even if I delete a file inside a container and commit it, size won't change. Then what is the point of deleting a file to save disk space...Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Found the logic: The problem is once i commit a CONTAINER of size say 17 GB and exit it a new image with size 17 GB is created. Even if run the image again and delete files inside them and recommit it, the size wont change. The point is before committing a container we must delete all the unnecessary files and commit the container